# Python Convert an IP address encoded in Base64 to a Decimal IP address

Tags: python, decimal, base64

I am very new to programming and Python so please bear with me.  I have a string that is Base64 and I want to convert it to decimal. The string can come in to the script as any value, for example zAvIAQ. This value represents an IP address which is 204.11.200.1 when converted to decimal. What I want to do is convert the Base64 string to decimal and assign it to a variable so that I can use it elsewhere in the script.

I have tried to use the base64.decode function, but that just gives me a very strange text output. I have tried to use the Decimal() function but that gives me an error. After searching for several days now I haven't found a way to do this, at least not one that I can understand. Any help that you can provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First decode the base64-encoded string using `decode('base64')` and then decode the resulting number into an IP quartet by using `socket.inet_ntoa`. Like this:

```
>>> socket.inet_ntoa('zAvIAQ=='.decode('base64'))
'204.11.200.1'
```

Comment: Thank you for the info it was very helpful.  The problem I am having is I want to feed the socket.inet_ntoa with the results of a variable as the base64 address will vary. Example: socket.inet_ntoa('peerRemoteAddr'.decode('base64').  Where peerRemoteAddr is a result (base64 address) of a variable I have  assigned.  Thank you

Comment: When I insert the variable into the socket I receive a Incorrect Padding Error

Comment: That's because you decided to chop up the value before sending it. The equal signs are important.

Comment: peerRemoteAddr = re.findall("BASE64:(.*?)=", Y) - This is how I have the findall to extract the b64 address from the string after the word BASE64

Comment: The equal signs are important.

Comment: re.findall('BASE64:(.*?)$', Y)

Comment: Well I get the desired output of ['zAvIAQ=='] from the findall but when I plug it in the socket I get: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'.

Comment: You can't get *both* and Incorrect Padding Error earlier *and* a missing attribute now. Something is off.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong.  It now works. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> address=[ord(c) for c in base64.b64decode('zAvIAQ==')]
>>> address
[204, 11, 200, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `base64.b64decode()`. With that you get:

```
In [18]: base64.b64decode('zAvIAQ==')
Out[18]: '\xcc\x0b\xc8\x01'
```

That is probably the weird output you were referring to. The point is that you get a byte string back, with each byte representing a value between 0 and 255. Those values might not be printable, hence the \x representation.

But as you know that these are the buckets of an IPv4 address, you go through them converting them to decimals, e.g. with the generator expression:

```
[ord(c) for c in ...]
```

and you get the more familiar representation 204, 11, 200, 1.

Comment: I was going to say something like this in my own answer but didn't have the time - thanks for filling in.